# Ejabberd: Authentication Failed

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have ejabberd server working properly. 
I can login on either iMessager or Audium.
I can login using the same account to  conversejs.org website.

The problem is when I used conversejs to my own domain it says "Authentication failed" and jabber logs print out " [warning] <0.4240.0>@shaper:new:87 Attempt to initialize an unspecified shaper 'deny'"

Did I missed up my client side config or server side config?

Comment: Looks like incorrect shaper configuration for ejabberd.

Comment: Yeah I can't figure out what part of the server side config.